# Como copiar um ponteiro de estrutura?

Tags: c, ponteiro, struct, memória

É possível clonar um ponteiro de estrutura? Segue o código:

```
typedef struct{
    int numero;
}estrutura;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

    estrutura *i = (estrutura *)malloc(sizeof(estrutura));
    estrutura *d;

    i->numero = 5;

    printf("%d", i->numero);

}
```

Eu quero que a estrutura `*d` por exemplo seja a cópia da estrutura `*i`, de forma que se eu alterar o valor de `i->numero`, não interfira no `d->numero`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A primeira coisa que precisa fazer é alocar memória para a outra estrutura. Depois deve copiar com [`memcpy()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/memcpy).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct {
    int numero;
} Estrutura;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    Estrutura *i = malloc(sizeof(Estrutura));
    Estrutura *d = malloc(sizeof(Estrutura));
    i->numero = 5;
    memcpy(d, i, sizeof(Estrutura));
    i->numero = 6;
    printf("%d", d->numero);
    printf("%d", i->numero);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/75ymDE). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/mgynuouh-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Struct/Copy.c).

Note que está copiando o conteúdo do objeto, porque o ponteiro sempre é copiado naturalmente.

Comment: eu fiz desta forma, porém não aloquei memória para *d, fiz a memcpy direto, isso poderia causar algum problema ?

Comment: Para onde copiou o objeto então?

Comment: Eu fiz o seguinte, memcpy(d, i, sizeof(estrutura));, sem utilizar malloc em *d

Comment: Isso não responde a pergunta que eu fiz.

Comment: Pelo que entendi, quando utilizei o memcpy, copiei o que estava na estrutura i para a d. Porém você me pediu para fazer uma malloc na estrutura d antes de utilizar o comando memcpy. Eu fiz o memcpy sem fazer este malloc para a estrutura d  e deu certo, gostaria de saber se isso pode causar algum problema ?

Comment: Você ainda não respondeu a pergunta que eu fiz. Qual o local da memória onde esse objeto foi copiado?

Comment: Desculpe não sei se entendi bem sua pergunta, seria no heap ?

Comment: E como você pode por um objeto no *heap*? Ou então, em que lugar do *heap*?

Comment: Fazendo a alocação, certo ?

Comment: Exatamente! E se não fizer a alocação vai por onde?